# Looping Through Large, Multidimensional Array Using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, function, for-loop, rcpp

I am trying to create models that involve looping through large multidimensional arrays (ex: dimensions = 20 x 1000 x 60), which run very slow the way I code them in R. I downloaded Rcpp and have been trying to implement such a model, since C++ handles loops very well. Normally, I would write such a function in R as:

```
fun <- function(x,y,z){
  f <- array(0, dim = c(18,50,10));
  for (i in 1:18){
    for (j in 1:50){
      for (l in 1:10){
        f[i,j,l] <- (i*j/10) + l;
      }
    }
  }
  return(f[x,y,z])
}
```

and as expected the function yields:

```
> fun(10,20,5)
[1] 25
```

This is what I thought the equivalent code in Rcpp should look like:

```
cppFunction('
  double fun(int x, int y, int z){
  int f[18][50][10] = {0};
  for (int i = 1; i > 18; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j > 50; j++){
      for (int l = 1; l > 10; l++){
        f[i][j][l] = (i * j/10) + l;
      }
    }
  }
  return f[x][y][z];
  }          
')
```

but I am getting 0's anytime I go to use the function.

```
> fun(10,20,5)
[1] 0
```

The actual models I'll be implementing use backward iteration, so I do need the arrays as part of the function. Alternatively, returning the array itself would also work for my purposes, but I haven't had luck with that either.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI, your you are using `C` type multidimensional arrays. There are better alternatives for your cases such as `RcppArmadillo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that C++ is 0 indexed. You need to start your indexing at 0 rather than 1 as in R. You also need to make sure that your loops only continue while the value of `i`, `j`, and `l` are *less than* the dimensions of the array (so switch `>` for `<`. And your array needs to be an array of `double`, not `int`:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  double fun(int x, int y, int z){
  double f[18][50][10] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++){
      for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++){
        f[i][j][l] = (i * j/10) + l;
      }
    }
  }
  return f[x][y][z];
  }          
')
```

Testing gives:

```r
fun(10, 20, 5)
#> [1] 25
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was actually calling the package Rcpp specifier that fixed it. I didn't realize it, but rstan was in my working library and I believe that program utilizes cppFunction.

And the < operator of course. 
 Thank you again!